# How to initialize a variable once in an if statement and use it outside the if statement

Tags: c, variables, scope, constants, global

I am trying to initialize an `int` with a particular value once only and use it repeatedly.

```
void some_method(int par){
    int ch=1;
  if (ch==1){
    int x = par;
  }
  int y = x + 2;
}
```

I know this code will definitely not work because `x` is only within the scope of the if statement. **some_method()** is called repeatedly in a while loop, so if I declare `x` outside the if statement  then every time **some_method()** is called, default to zero. I just want `x` to remain constant. I thought about just making `x` a global variable, but I am sure there has got to be a better solution than that. Any suggestions will be helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Use the static keyword: `static int x = some value;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `static` variables:

```
void some_method(...)
{
  static int initialized = 0, x;

  if(!initialized)
  {
    x = ...
    initialized = 1;
  }
  /* Use x. */
}
```

Note that you then need to "pay" for the check of `initialized` on every call, but if the work done to compute the value of `x` is expensive enough it might be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variable "x" outside of the if block, but declare it as static:

```
void some method (some parameter) {
    static int x = some_default_value; // this is your default value
    inx y = x + 2;
 }
```

Alternatively, if you're only using your code there, and x is a constant, you can just define it using a `#define` outside of your method.